# Shell Script to Stop an Executable JAR in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jar

I use the below command for getting the PID of the jar file. But currently no jar files are running. But still i get some random numbers printed. I am scared about to call the command kill -9 $PID. 
Can anyone share what is that random number mean? Why it is printed even if the jar file not running.

```
PID=`ps -ef | grep RushMiddleLayer | awk '{ print $2 }'`
echo $PID
```

the random numbers like 423, 461, 457 like that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ps -ef | grep` is finding it's own `grep` line in `ps`, and returning the pid of the `grep` process. If it actuallyfound a result, it would return two or more lines or results. You can examine the output of your command yourself to verify, replacing the last command `awk ...` with `less`.

You could use a regex "trick" and use this grep instead, so it doesn't find it's own `grep` process:

grep [R]ushMiddleLayer

But `awk` will still return multiple pid's in multiple lines if there are several "RushMiddleLayer"'s running. I trust the rest of your commands can handle that.